# Detect semitransparent pattern in an image with changing backgrounds

Tags: image-processing

I'm writing an image analyzer and I'm having trouble detecting an specific semitransparent pattern that is rendered on any number of complex backgrounds.

Here is an example with the pattern:
[image: example]

I tried finding similar ranges of luminance and saturation, the NTSC formula for gray scaling, binarizing and nothing worked well. I am all out of ideas.

How can one go about processing this kind of image to achieve what I need?

Enlarged:

[image: enlarged example]

Comment: sobel your data in x and y, compose as 2-channel image. then try filter2D or matchTemplate. -- if you can, find a clean template for this cross. is it a game resource you can extract? if not, then at least get some screenshots of it on flat backgrounds (black/gray/white) -- how many instances per picture do you expect to exist? do you have a larger picture as a sample to work with?

Comment: I didn't know about Sobel. Tried it online and it looks promising. I don't have the template, but I will see if I can crack it. Only 1 instance, in a small image, 30x30, max 50x50